# Value for $\Bbb P (A \cup B \cup C) $

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

Let $A,B,C$ be events in a probability space. Suppose that 
$\mathbb P(A) = 1/4\\
\mathbb P(B^c) = 2/3\\
\mathbb P(C) = 1/2\\
\mathbb P(A^c\cap B) = 1/4\\
\mathbb P(A\cap C) = 0\\
\mathbb P(B^c\cup C^c) = 5/6. $

I want to calculate the value of  $\mathbb P(A\cup B\cup C)$.

My work:
I calculated that $\mathbb P(B)= 1/3, \mathbb P(A \cap B) = 1/12$  and  $\mathbb P(B \cap C) =1/6 $.
And I know that $\Bbb P (A \cup B \cup C) = \Bbb P (A) + \Bbb P (B) + \Bbb P (C) - \Bbb P (A\cap B) - \Bbb P (B\cap C) -\Bbb P (A\cap C) + \Bbb P (A \cap B \cap C)\\ = 5/6 + \Bbb P (A \cap B \cap C) $. 
My question is: Can I use the fact that $0 \leq \Bbb P (A\cap B \cap C ) \leq \Bbb P (A\cap C ) = 0 \Rightarrow  \Bbb P (A\cap B \cap C)=0$ to say that $\Bbb P (A \cup B \cup C) =5/6$?

Comment: Yes, if $P(A\cap C)=0$ then certainly $P(A \cap B \cap C)=0$.   But I have a question ... how did you determine $P(B \cap C)$?

Comment: More pressingly, how is it that $P(B^C \cap C^C)>P(B^C)$?!  I am guessing you just made a typo and you were given that $P(B^C \cup C^C)=5/6$ rather than $P(B^C \cap C^C)=5/6$ ... and hence indeed $P(B \cap C)=1/6$ .. am I right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm so sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: I believe that property is called monotonicity. If $X \subseteq Y$ then $\mu(X) \leq (Y)$ for any measure $\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Since $A \cap B \cap C \subseteq A \cap C$, $0 \leq \Pr(A \cap B \cap C) \leq \Pr(A \cap C) = 0 \implies \Pr(A \cap B \cap C) = 0$.